# QAD Plugin - Dimension Style, can't detect Text layer

Tags: qgis-plugins, dimensions

I am creating dimension style using QAD plugin in QGIS.I followed the documentation requirements that it only needs a point layer with text field. Yet it cant detect the layer. Any help? [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

QAD supports all types of vector layers of QGIS with a distinction regarding the point layer. In fact, QAD manage layers of QGIS distinguishing between symbols layers and text layers. The first displays symbols while the second displays texts.
The text layer is a layer that displays labels only. It is a QGIS point layer with the following characteristics:

1. the symbol must have a minimum of 90% transparency
2. must have a label
   Layers that are not textual will be considered as symbol layers.